# How does string immutability improve security?

Tags: java, string, security, immutability

It is common to hear that strings are immutable and this improves security.
I understand the idea that since strings are final, their contents cannot be changed later. But even if the content could be changed, i think it is still safe as the code is written by developer instead of attacker. Or else in practice, how does this attack are being done actually?

I saw an example online that indicated an attacker could bypass security if strings were mutable. I don't get it. The below code is written by service provider. This is the part attacker can never touch. Whether strings are mutable or not attackers can never modify their values, right?

```
public class FileInputStream
{
 private String filename;
 public FileInputStream(String filename)
 {
  if (!allowedToReadFile(filename))
  throw new SecurityException();
  this.filename = filename;
  }
  ...
 }
```

Comment: In addition to the linked question and the answer below, note that it also (and maybe most importantly) protects you from inadvertent mistakes that you as the developer would make which could lead to security issues. For example a security check not performed could be a result of you mutating a string.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Strings are mutable. In the constructor the the filename gets checked and a reference to the string is stored in the object. There might be another method that opens the file using that filename. If the contents of the string were modified to another filename before calling that method, then the method opens the new file without failing the `allowedToReadFile` check, which would have happened when the String with the new contents was passed at the start. In this case the attacker has access to almost any file by bypassing the check and changing the contents of the string later.

In general making data immutable can avoid many security problems an other problems. If Strings were mutable in Java, it wouldn't prevent you from changing the contents of the string from another thread. You might even notice that the string changed during a function call. Printing half of the old string and half of the new string to the screen. It might even mess with Unicode encoding. An other question to ask would be, what happens with literals, when you change them? Waste memory and create a new instance of the string represented by the literal? Or create only one String for one literal. If Strings were mutable, there should have been an other system to copy objects, maybe a system like in C++, in which Strings are indeed mutable. Assigning Strings copies them. But this comes at a cost: Copying or the need of a new complex language feature tha allows moving, borrowing, and const reference passing to functions. The JVM is not designed for those features.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that if string is mutable, there may be chance that filenames could be modified later and unexpected file got opened, but i would wonder that the method is written by developer, how attacker change the variables that stored the checked filenames?

Comment: @jason: I suppose you would have to read one of the many "hackers" books to find out.  One possibility is writing a program in assembler to monitor the Java program and make in-memory changes to Strings as the application runs.

Comment: it sounds somehow abstract, could you give an example of how to achieve attack about changing to open another unexpected file by this?